# as.numeric function not working in a nester for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, data-class, nested-for-loop

```
for (i in c(1:ncol(final_targets))) {
  for (j in c(2:nrow(final_targets))) {
  final_targets[j,i] <- as.numeric(final_targets[j,i])
  }
}
```

> data.class(final_targets[2,1])
> [1] "character"

The output always shows as character no matter what I use. I tried as.integer, as.double. Didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

We need only a single loop instead of nested loop.  The `type`s are specific for a column and it can be directly assigned.   But, if we loop over the rows as well and then try to assign each element of row, it wouldn't work because the other values are `character` and the column type remains as `character`

```
for(i in seq_along(final_targets)) {
     final_targets[,i] <- as.numeric(final_targets[,i])
 }
```

Comment: The main purpose of the nested loop was to avoid turning the first row of the dataframe to numeric. How do I do that without the nested?

Comment: @SiddarthReddy It is not possible as I mentioned in the description that a unit in data.frame is a column and types are specific for column and not by element unless you change it to a `list` column

Comment: @SiddarthReddy you can't have multiple types in a single column

Answer (score 1):

The function `as.numeric()` is vectorized. No need to have nested loops, just loop over the columns as mentioned by akrun.

---

You can also easily do that with `dplyr`,

```
final_targets%>%mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))
```

---

With base R

```
sapply(final_targets, as.numeric)
```

---

Or with `purrr`

```
map_dbl(final_targets, as.numeric)
```